# Posicionar un logo sobre otra imagen

Tags: php, imagen

Estoy haciendo que el usuario suba una imagen de un logo y luego intento posicionarla sobre otra imagen que tengo en el servidor.

La posición en donde irá superpuesta la reccibo como parámetros por POST. El logo que recibo es siempre un png, que puede o no tener fondo transparente y se debe mantener ese mismo fondo.

**El problema:** no sé por qué me crea espacios negros, ¿pueden decirme qué error cometo?

**Código**:

```
session_start();
$posiX =    $_POST['x'];
$posiY = $_POST['y'];

$datoImg = $_SESSION['genImg'];

$logo = $datoImg['logo']; //'logo.png'
$fondo = 'original.jpg';

foto($fondo, $logo, $posiX, $posiY);

function foto($img_original, $marcadeagua, $posiX, $posiY){
    $trozosimagenorig=explode(".",$img_original);
    $extensionimagenorig=$trozosimagenorig[count($trozosimagenorig)-1];
    if (preg_match("/jpg|jpeg|JPG|JPEG/", $extensionimagenorig)) {
        $imgm=imagecreatefromjpeg($img_original);
    }
    if (preg_match("/png|PNG/", $extensionimagenorig)) {
        $imgm=imagecreatefrompng($img_original);
    }
    if (preg_match("/gif|GIF/", $extensionimagenorig)) {
        $imgm=imagecreatefromgif($img_original);
    }

    $marcadeagua= imagecreatefrompng($marcadeagua);

    $xmarcaagua = $posiX;
    $ymarcaagua = $posiY;
    $ximagen= imagesx($imgm);
    $yimagen=imagesy($imgm);

    imagecopy($imgm, $marcadeagua, $xmarcaagua, $ymarcaagua,
     0, 0, $xmarcaagua, $ymarcaagua);
    //se copia la imagen
    imagejpeg($imgm,'../assets/originalrand.jpg');
}
```

**Resultado obtenido:** crea esos espacios negros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Imágenes originales:**

Imagen de fondo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagen de logo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que tiene la funcion `imagecreatefromjpeg`? y las demas funciones?

Comment: @sioesi son funciones de php para crear imagenes.

Comment: @sioesi http://php.net/manual/es/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php <-- es muy bueno el soporte nativo de PHP para manipular imágenes (sencillo y divertido)

Comment: un gran favor, estoy tratando de hacer lo mismo pero no soy nada bueno programando , me podrias compartir tus archivos para ver donde me estoy equivocando o utiizar tu codigo .
Saludos y Gracias...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La verdad que ya casi lo tenías solucionado. Para copiar una imagen sobre otra, se usa (prestar atención al orden de cada argumento):

```
bool imagecopy ( resource $dst_im , resource $src_im , 
                      int $dst_x  , int $dst_y , 
                      int $src_x  , int $src_y , 
                      int $src_w  , int $src_h )
```

Separé los argumentos para que se lea mejor. La primera línea toma los recursos de imágenes (normalmente generados con [`imagecreatefrom***()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.imagecreatefrompng.php)). Luego las posiciones en el destino donde se ubicará la imagen (`$dst_x` , `$dst_y`), las posiciones desde donde se tomará del origen (`$src_x` , `$src_y`), y las dimensiones a tomar del origen (`$src_w` , `$src_h`).

Teniendo esto en claro, el resto es ubicar esos valores (comento en el código).

#### Código

```
<?php

//cambio los valores a unos fijos como prueba para que quede más claro
$posiX = 400;
$posiY = 150;
$logo = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1TyX.png';
$fondo = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChYVl.jpg';

foto($fondo, $logo, $posiX, $posiY);

function foto($img_original, $marcadeagua, $posiX, $posiY){
    //Crear el destino (fondo)
    if (preg_match("/\.jpe?g$/i", $img_original)) { //simplifiqué el regex
        $imgm = imagecreatefromjpeg($img_original);
    }
    elseif (preg_match("/\.png$/i", $img_original)) {
        $imgm = imagecreatefrompng($img_original);
    }
    elseif (preg_match("/\.gif$/i", $img_original)) {
        $imgm = imagecreatefromgif($img_original);
    }

    //tomar el origen (logo)
    $marcadeagua= imagecreatefrompng($marcadeagua);

    //las posiciones en donde ubicar - se reciben por POST (hardcoddeadas en este ejemplo)
    $xmarcaagua = $posiX;
    $ymarcaagua = $posiY;
    //se obtiene el ancho y el largo del logo
    $ximagen = imagesx($marcadeagua);
    $yimagen = imagesy($marcadeagua);

    //COPIAR (observar las variables que se usan)
    imagecopy($imgm, $marcadeagua, 
              $xmarcaagua, $ymarcaagua,
              0, 0,
              $ximagen, $yimagen);


    //Generar el archivo
    imagejpeg($imgm, '../assets/originalrand.jpg');


    //faltaba destruirla (hay que ser prolijos)
    imagedestroy( $imgm );
}
```

#### Resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Subí un ejemplo ejecutándose a un hosting gratuito: http://mariano.freevar.com/70835/

---

**Extras:**

1. Servir la imagen

   Si en vez de generar un archivo, quisieras que el PHP sirva la imagen:

   ```
   header( "Content-type: image/jpeg" );
   imagejpeg($imgm);
   ```
2. Generar fondo transparente en el logo si no lo tiene

   Digamos que el logo tiene un fondo blanco. Si quisiéramos que todo el blanco se tome como transparente:

   ```
   //tomar el origen (logo)
   $marcadeagua= imagecreatefrompng($marcadeagua);

   // asignar un recurso con color blanco
   $fondoBlanco = imagecolorallocate($marcadeagua, 255, 255, 255);
   // Hacer que el blanco sea transparente
   imagecolortransparent($marcadeagua, $fondoBlanco);

   // y luego lo copiamos sobre la otra imagen ......
   ```